# Propel 2 double join on custom field

Tags: php, postgresql, join, propel

I'm trying to create a query with propel that joins a first table called Entry with a second table called Company that have 3 fields related to a third table called User.

Entry

- id
- field1
- field2
- company_id

Company

- id
- field1
- field2
- user_id1
- user_id2
- user_id3

User

- id
- name
- surname
- team

I want to be able to join Entry to Company by company_id and then join to the table User using the field userid1.

I tried different ways like

```
EntryQuery::create()->joinWith('Company')->joinWith("User")
```

but  I get and error saying that Entry has no relation with user

or

```
EntryQuery::create()->useCompanyQuery()->joinWith("User")->endUse()
```

but I still get an error that Company has no relation with User, even though all the user fields in Company have a relation with User in the database.

There is any way to specify the field on the join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it, I'm not sure if it's the best one but works.

```
EntryQuery::create()
->useCompanyQuery()
    ->innerJoinUserRelatedByUserId1()
->endUse()
->with("Company")
->with("UserRelatedByUserId1")
```

This hydrates all the relations.